# DSC Composite Resource Parameters not showing up on Azure State DSC

Tags: azure, dsc

I'm doing an example for composite resources, I had created the folder structure and the manifest and I'm able to import it and see it available in the automation account, but for some reason when I create the parameters in the schema.psm1, I can't see the parameters being available in the automation account composite resources module. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Mandatory_Params_not_passed]

```
Configuration FeatureInstall {       

Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDscResources    

param(  
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]  
[string[]]$EnsureFeature,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string[]]$NameFeature,    

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string[]]$IncludeAllSubFeatures  
)

WindowsFeature Features  
{  
 Ensure = $EnsureFeature  
 Name = $NameFeature  
 IncludeAllSubFeature = $IncludeAllSubFeatures  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question I was doing this wrong, here is the way that worked for me.

```
Configuration FeatureInstall
{        

param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]
$Feature,

[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]
$EnsureFeature,

[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]
$NameFeature,

[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]
$IncludeAllSubFeatures
)

WindowsFeatureSet $Feature
{
Ensure = $EnsureFeature
Name = $NameFeature
IncludeAllSubFeature = $IncludeAllSubFeatures
}       
}
```